# Docker, postgres, sqlalchemy - could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Hi I am trying setup my project on docker. The structure looks like this

```
Project

-- docker-compose.yml

-- docker
   -- app
     -- Dockerfile
     -- my-project-0.1.tar.gz

   -- db
     -- Dockerfile
     -- db_dump.dump
```

The docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    build: ./docker/db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  app:
    build: ./docker/app
    depends_on:
     - db
    command: getdatacommand
    restart: always
```

app/Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM python:3

COPY myproject-0.1.tar.gz /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp

RUN pip install myproject-0.1.tar.gz

# SETUP DB ENVIROMENT VARIABLES
ENV DB_DRIVER='postgres'
ENV DB_HOST='db'
ENV DB_PORT='5432'
ENV DB_USERNAME='myuser'
ENV DB_PASSWORD='secretpass'
ENV DB_DBNAME='db-dev'
...

EXPOSE 5000
```

I refered to: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/ for creating my postgres Dockerfile

my db dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

# SETUP DB ENVIROMENT VARIABLES
ENV BB_DB_PORT='5432'
ENV BB_DB_USERNAME='myuser'
ENV BB_DB_PASSWORD='secretpass'
ENV BB_DB_DBNAME='db-dev'

COPY bb-dev.dump /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-software-properties software-properties-common postgresql-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3

USER postgres

# Start postgres create db and restore dump
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command psql --command "CREATE USER ${BB_DB_USERNAME} WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD '${BB_DB_PASSWORD}';" &&\
    createdb -O ${BB_DB_USERNAME} ${BB_DB_DBNAME} &&\
    psql ${BB_DB_DBNAME} < bb-dev.dump

# Adjust PostgreSQL configuration so that remote connections to the
# database are possible.
RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf

# And add ``listen_addresses`` to ``/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf``
RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

# Expose the PostgreSQL port
EXPOSE ${BB_DB_PORT}

# Set the default command to run when starting the container
CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf"]
```

However, when I run `docker-compose up` I get a `connection refused error`.
Event though I can access the postgres container from the host machine like this:

`psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d db-dev -U myuser --password`

Am I missing something obvious?

**Update**

To make sure the database is ready before app starts reading from it, I modified my `docker-compose` file to look like this:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  db:
    build: ./docker/db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "pg_isready -h localhost -p 5432 -U myuser"]
        interval: 30s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 5
  app:
    build: ./docker/app
    depends_on:
        db:
            condition: service_healthy
    command: getdatacommand
    restart: always
```

The app container in this case fails to start and I get a message saying `container is unhealthy`. However the pg_isready works fine if I comment out the app container and run `docker-compose up` with just the `db` container

Comment: The db container might be slow to start and the app container expects it to be up instantly, which might be causing the issue. See https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/compose/production/django/entrypoint.sh#L28 for a possible workaround if that is indeed the case.

Comment: But shouldn't the `depends_on` value automatically make sure that the `db` is up before starting `app` container?

Comment: the postgres container being up doesn't mean the database server is ready for incoming connections. It just means the container is up (and getting setup, or is setup)

Comment: I tried what you suggested and this time used a `healthcheck` in my `docker-compose.yml`. That didn't solve it. I've updated my question

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue. It had something to do with the fact that I was using different images for my two `Dockerfiles`
`from ubuntu` and `from python3`

I changed the app container to use `from ubuntu` and installed python and the issue went away. 
Here is my modified `app` container `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update \ 
    && apt-get install -y software-properties-common curl \ 
    && add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6 \ 
    && apt-get remove -y software-properties-common \ 
    && apt autoremove -y \ 
    && apt-get update \ 
    && apt-get install -y python3.6 \ 
    && curl -o /tmp/get-pip.py "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" \ 
    && python3.6 /tmp/get-pip.py \ 
    && apt-get remove -y curl \ 
    && apt autoremove -y \ 
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY myproject-0.1.tar.gz /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp

RUN pip install myproject-0.1.tar.gz

# SETUP DB ENVIROMENT VARIABLES
ENV DB_DRIVER='postgres'
ENV DB_HOST='db'
ENV DB_PORT='5432'
ENV DB_USERNAME='myuser'
ENV DB_PASSWORD='secretpass'
ENV DB_DBNAME='db-dev'
...

EXPOSE 5000
```

Hope this helps someone in the same predicament.